# Updating iphone 4s OS 5.1.1 to ANYTHING more current 6.1.1? 7.0?

Tags: ios, iphone, restore, software-update

I have not updated my iphone 4s since the day I got it. I am still on IOS 5.1.1. I jailbroke the phone when i first got it, but the jailbreak was outdated and stopped working so I deleted it off the iphone. If i want to update my IOS can I just backup my files and hit update on my phone or itunes to a more updated IOS ? I do not wish to jailbreak my phone afterwards, I dont need it. My concern was in the past i heard that if you updated your OS with a jailbroken phone, the phone goes into a loop on the restart. I had this happen to my on my iphone 3G. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> can I just backup my files and hit update on my phone

## Yes.

---

Pressing the Update button will cause a jailbroken iPhone to 'go wrong', usually resulting in a reboot loop. **Pressing Update on a non-jailbroken iPhone is fine, even if it was previously jailbroken.**

To update a jailbroken device, removing the jailbreak…

1. **Backup** the device using either iTunes or iCloud.
2. **Restore** the device. You can use a previously-downloaded IPSW, or let iTunes download the latest one for you.
3. **Restore from backup**. When setting up your iPhone, choose to restore from backup and let iTunes/iCloud restore the backup.